# What are the best practices to use Aerospike bin name?

Tags: java, caching, aerospike

I am working in spring boot with Aerospike for caching. I am not able to understand how to use bin name for storing the data. What bin name signifies?

Answer (score 2):

Bin name is limited to 15 characters in Aerospike and is stored with each record when persisting the record on SSDs. (There is no schema in Aerospike, each record is self describing.) For latest Aerospike version, a shorter bin name will save you storage space. Those bytes can add up! You can define / use up to max 32K bin names. Once a bin name is used, it cannot be deleted from the system (without restart). If you download Aerospike CE and register yourself, you get free access to intro module of Aerospike Academy.  There is a free - an hour long or so training module on Introduction to Aerospike. Highly recommend going that route before you get started.

Specifically, Aerospike stores a record against a key. The record comprises one or more bins. In each bin you can store values - which can be integer, string, float, maps, lists, BLOBs, geoJson objects etc.  Maps and Lists are the most powerful for data modeling. A bin of the same name can hold different data type between different records - i.e. no schema - though from a data modeling perspective, one would typically never do it.